# Executing programs on TinyCore (TinyRocketConfig)

Tags: rocket-chip

I am trying to write executable programs to simulate using Verilator, but it seems like I am doing something wrong, as even the most simple program doesn't seem to run on the `TinyRocketConfig`.

The C code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "mmio.h"

int main(void)
{
  uint32_t uint_32bits = 0x0FU;
  
  printf("%#x", uint_32bits);
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program on Verilator on the normal `RocketConfig` it works, but when I try to do the same on the `TinyRocketConfig` it gets stuck forever without giving any output:

```
./simulator-chipyard-TinyRocketConfig-debug ../../tests/32b_test.riscv run-binary
This emulator compiled with JTAG Remote Bitbang client. To enable, use +jtag_rbb_enable=1.
Listening on port 35177
[UART] UART0 is here (stdin/stdout).
```

Having to cancel the execution manually after some time, any idea of why?
Thanks for any answer and sorry for my little knowledge on the topic.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with the stack size needed to run these tests. TinyRocketConfig only has 4KiB of backing memory by default. Have you tried increasing the DCache's number of sets so you can have 1MiB of backing memory? If that fixes it, it's a linker script issue with the stack size and the linker script will need some adjustments for TinyCore.

Comment: @metzkorn I have incremented the DCache of the TinyCore to 1 Mb and I am still in the same situation, any other possible ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you compile this with the normal gcc instructions? If I remember correctly, those are targetting 64bit. I think you'll need to use the 32-bit gcc equivalents when compiling for TinyCore.

Comment: That might definitely be the issue, I will let you know as soon as I manage to compile for 32-bits as I am having some issues with it. Thanks

Comment: You can try passing `-march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32` to `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` and see if that works. As described here https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard/issues/23

Comment: The more advanced route would be building the rv32 toolchain from rocket-tools. https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-tools/blob/master/build-rv32ima.sh Definitely reach out on the chipyard google group about running rv32 tests.